# Transform Map to object using Guava?

Tags: java, object, dictionary, guava

Using Guava, is it possible to convert a Map to a Set or List of objects containing the keys and values of the Map? E.g. given something like

```
class MyEntry {
    public String key;
    public String value;
}

Map<String,String> theMap = new Map<String,String>();
```

I am missing something like this in Guava / did not find it:

```
Set<MyEntry> myEntries = Maps.transform(theMap, transformFunction<<Map<String,String>, MyEntry>);
```

Obviously it's not hard to do this manually, still I am wondering if I missed something and Guava really doesn't support such a thing?

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest thing you can do with Guava would be something like

```
Collection<MyEntry> myEntries = Collections2.transform(map.entrySet(), function);
```

which is just a normal transformation on the `entrySet` of the `map`, and `function` has the type `Function<Map.Entry<String, String>, MyEntry>`.

Guava can't provide `Sets.transform` for a variety of reasons -- it can't guarantee the function is injective, it doesn't have an inverse to the function, etc.  If you need a `Set`, then you're probably best off just doing the manual loop.

Comment: Neat "trick", I was too focused on the Maps class directly and didn't think of the map.entrySet() method. Thanks for this hint :-) Should be even possible to use this with a FluentIterable, my prefered way :-)